# How to programmatically update a file field

Tags: entities, files, nodes

I have a file field (audio recordings) on a node. So all these files are located in sites/default/files/recordings. I have set in the settings that those files are now stored in subfolders by taxonomy. It works nicely, but now I have to put the older files into subfolders to.

I'm writing a script for that. So I just want to put the file in a subfolder of the taxonomy that the node belongs to. It's trivial to move a file (php function rename does it), but how to update a record in a database? I've tried this in many ways, but cannot find the solution for this simple task.

One approach that appear logical would be something like this:

```
foreach($nodes as $n) {
    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $n);
    $uriold = $n->field_recording['en'][0]['uri'];
    $urinew = generate_new_uri($uriold);
    move_recording($uriold, $urinew);
    $recording = $n->field_recording;
    $recording['en'][0]['uri'] = $urinew;
    $node_wrapper->field_recording->set($recording);   //error
    $node_wrapper->save();
}
```

The exception is thrown: 'EntityMetadataWrapperException' with message 'Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.'

Another approach would be to use the Drupal's file_move function:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_move/

But after a few hours of trying to call the function properly I gave up. I couldn't find out how to get stdClass from $n->field_recording.